# com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException during gradle 'testDebug' on android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I have an Android Studio project with the latest 1.15.2 crashlytics.
It works well when i build and run on my device.
However after crashlytic's setup my tests fails on gradle 'testDebug'.

**Output is**

```
....app.entity.ConfigurationTest > parseTest FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException
            Caused by: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException
```

It can be related to the call of an activity `onCreate` method during the test preparation. And in the `onCreate` i have a line

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

It looks like it works differently in `test` scope.

**How can i solve this or skip the crashlytics at all during tests?**
F.e. here is a solution which works for one person but it either don't work for me or i am putting it in invalid gradle section.

```
debug {
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}
```

[CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395501/crashlyticsmissingdependencyexception)

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app/app.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.15.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “…”
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName “…”
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
        …
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'

    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.0'

    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.0'

    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    androidTestCompile ('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3')
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

More output after looking in tests results files

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

    at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.onPreExecute(Crashlytics.java:347)
    at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.onPreExecute(Crashlytics.java:229)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:27)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:594)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:26)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:49)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:417)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:364)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:321)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:292)
    at app.AppApplication.onCreate(AppApplication.java:32)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:164)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

    at com.crashlytics.android.BuildIdValidator.validate(BuildIdValidator.java:59)
    at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.onPreExecute(Crashlytics.java:306)
    ... 48 more
```

**Workaround** (works for me)

Temporarily i've fixed it for me using the following approach:
I've created a class

```
public class CrashlyticsFacade {

    public static boolean enableCrashlytics = true;

    public static void initCrashlytics(Application application) {
        if (enableCrashlytics) {
            Fabric.with(application, new Crashlytics());
        }
    }

    public static void log(int priority, String tag, String msg) {
        if (enableCrashlytics) {
            Crashlytics.log(priority, tag, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void identify(String userIdentifier, String userName, String email) {
        if (enableCrashlytics) {
            if (userIdentifier != null) {
                Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(userIdentifier);
            }
            if (userName != null) {
                Crashlytics.setUserName(userName);
            }
            if (email != null) {
                Crashlytics.setUserEmail(email);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setEnableCrashlytics(boolean value) {
        CrashlyticsFacade.enableCrashlytics = value;
    }
```

And i am using it as a facade to Crashlytics in app code and tests.
Additionally in test class i have to use

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    CrashlyticsFacade.setEnableCrashlytics(false);
}
```

since robolectric uses separate classloader for tests

Comment: More output after debug

Comment: Not sure, but in your build.gradle you've `ext.enableCrashlytics = false`, what if you remove this line?

Comment: Konrad, i have apiSecret in crashlytics.properties

Comment: Marcus, with or without this line result is the same. Initially i've got an error without 'ext.enableCrashlytics = false' and it appeared as a one of the variant to try but i've checked it right now one more time.

Comment: I can assume that it can be related to apiKey and apiSecret key anyway. Maybe it reads it differently on test scope or looking for another location of the crashlytics.properties file.

Comment: I will look into direction how tests are reading manifest. It is the only place crashlytics reading the apiKey

Comment: I met exactly the same issue. I implemented your workaround and it works. I sent a support message to crashlytics but they have not answered so far. There is definitely something strange happening between crashlytics and roboelectric.

Comment: I did the same, they just ignored :)
Robolectric uses a custom class loader and also can use test/mock manifest which can be one of root cause.

Comment: Thanks, My app work with fabric installation. after remove ext.enableCrashlytics = false

Answer (score 12):

I found another solution. If you are using robolectric in tests (If not, you can add it or use answer provided by @Rostislav) you can override your application class and skip Crashlytics initialization.

```
// MyApplication.java in src\main\java

public class MyAplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupCrashlytics();
    }

    protected void setupCrashlytics() {
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    }
}
```

=======

```
// TestMyAplication.java in src\test\java
/**
 * Robolectric uses class with name Test<ApplicationClassName> as test variant of the application
 * class. We use test application for API class injection so we need test version of this class.
 */
public class TestMyAplication extends MyAplication {

    @Override
    protected void setupCrashlytics() {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/OkBuilds/OkBuck/issues/10

https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html

I fixed this problem by add `<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">RANDOM_UUID</string>` to strings.xml

Comment: i am at 1.22 build gradle version and it worked for me.