# Can not seem to get crashlytics running on our Android app / io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

Can not seem to get crashlytics running on our Android app. iOS is working fine.
on Android I keep getting a io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException

With the message: 
This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

Been reading these posts:

- [CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395501/crashlyticsmissingdependencyexception)
- https://twittercommunity.com/t/app-crash-on-startup-with-crashlytics/56703/5

But so far can't find the sollution

Running AS 2.0-beta6
with gradle plugin gradle:2.0.0-beta6

Anyone??

*edit: I am already signed up at fabric.io. Am logged in to the dashboard where the iOS version of our app is already hooked up, but added the Android app isn't working so far.

*edit2: I have the plugin installed, went through the install process and followed the configurration, compiled and ran the app, but as soon as Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); gets executed it crashes the app giving me the above error and saying I should sign up. Problem is I am already signed up.

*edit3: Okay so i got as far as at least not running into the UnmetDependencyException. Sollution was to add the meta data with to io.fabric.apiKey to another module of my project's manifest file. Now i run into the problem that even though my app starts, my Android app is not recognized in the fabric dashboard. So if anyone knows a way to solve that?

*edit4: Got the issue fixed. Sent an email to fabric's support and it seemed to be an issue on their side. They patch it up and now the android version of our app  is also showing in the dashboard.

Comment: which dependency is that?

Comment: do you have `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }` repository included and `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'` added as dependency

Comment: Yes. Repo and classpath where added to gradle files...

Comment: ah seems you haven't signed up according to the message `Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up, install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.`

Comment: but that's the strange thing. I am signed up. I'm even logged in to the fabric dashboard and when i click on the the link I'm immediately  redirected to the  apps page (iOS already hooked up there)

Comment: in the dashboard click on the crashlitics icon

Comment: Yip, automatically selected when i lget redirected (from logcat) to  fabric dashboard. It show me all the crashes of our iOS app, but as before no possibility to hook up my android app

Comment: Todd from Fabric here. A few steps for future people finding this issue. We suggest running ./gradlew assemble --refresh-dependencies when you get dependency errors. After that try enabling debug mode and trying again. These two steps get most people up and running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That happened the first time to me, I had to:

1. Install the Fabric plugin to (Eclipse by that time, Android Studio right now)
2. Follow the configuration the plugin suggested
3. Compile and run the app once, as the plugin suggested.
4. Optionally, crash the app to ensure Crashlytics is triggered.

Remember that the Fabric app you install on OS X is not the same as the used for Android.

Comment: yes I have the plugin installed, went through the install process and followed the configurration, compiled and ran the app, but as soon as Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); gets executed it crashes the app giving me the above error and saying I should sign up. Problem is I am already signed up.

Comment: @RikvanVelzen yes I think you are added to the iOS app, but not to the android app

Comment: Okay so i got as far as at least not running into the UnmetDependencyException. Sollution was to add the meta data with to io.fabric.apiKey to another module of my project's manifest file. Now i run into the problem that even though my app starts, my Android app is not recognized in the fabric dashboard. So if anyone knows a way to solve that?

Comment: hey, it seems that Crashlytics captures crashes only when app is connected to Android Studio. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

in fabric dashboard i have to enable answers which include crashlytics.